# "Batch Script" task on VSTS build definition does not activate Conda environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Assuming a Anaconda3 environment was installed in the prefix path ENV_PATH and that ACTIVATE points to the Anaconda's activate.bat script, VSTS Batch Script task fails to execute the following code inside pip_install_conda.bat:

```
call %ACTIVATE% %ENV_PATH%
pip install pytest
call %DEACTIVATE%
```

The issue is that the call to "call %ACTIVATE% %ENV_PATH%" seems not to have effect in the sense that the commands executed by ACTIVATE are not visible to the current VSTS terminal session (maybe a new terminal was forked and discarded after activate.bat execution finished). If ACTIVATE had succeeded, pip would be in the PATH. The log is:

```
2018-08-02T00:05:54.0408670Z ##[debug]Working directory: 'C:\agent\_work\6\s'
2018-08-02T00:05:54.0408670Z ##[debug]Fail on standard error: 'False'
2018-08-02T00:05:54.0408670Z ##[debug]Modify environment: 'False'
2018-08-02T00:05:54.0408670Z ##[debug]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\agent\_work\6\s\pip_install_conda.bat "
2018-08-01T23:52:45.0572875Z 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2018-08-01T23:52:45.0572875Z 
2018-08-01T23:52:45.0572875Z operable program or batch file.
2018-08-01T23:52:45.0572875Z C:\agent\_work\6\s>pip install pytest 
2018-08-01T23:52:45.1062463Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
2018-08-01T23:52:45.1092469Z ##[debug]System.Exception: Process completed with exit code 1.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.ProcessHandler.<RunAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.<RunStepAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

If I connect to the Agent machine (or any other machine) and run this script manually, it will work.

If I run line by line on a command prompt on any machine, it will also work.

There is something in the way this Batch Script task runs that prevents the conda environment to be loaded. activate.bat basically sets some environment variables and run other *.bat files to setup other internal stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct -- the batch script doesn't work because each build step runs in its own process.  Use the [Conda Environment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/package/conda-environment?view=vsts) to activate the environment and subsequent build steps will run in the environment.

Comment: The aforementioned issue happens in a single build step